# Create custom trigger for RabbitMQ queues in Zabbix

Tags: rabbitmq, zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I'm pretty new to Zabbix and I need it to create single custom triggers for single Rabbit queues or groups of queues(in the easiest/fastest/scalable way possible, because i have 200+ queues).

The trigger per se is kinda easy, I only need it to find out when the queues has no consumer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a ready template from zabbix share:  https://www.zabbix.com/integration_search?search=RabbitMQ

Comment: Yeah, but, in my understanding, you have to use dll to choose singular queues, because that is where the discovery of queues is, the templates gives you a general overview over all the queues, you cannot set limits on singular queues